# Setting timeout for Google Adwords api

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

We are using Google Adwords APIs (v201710) to get customer information, adGroup and campaign information.

The default timeout is set as 20 minutes by Google Adwords. This is causing issues as our threads are getting hanged if we get **Read Timed Out** exception.

**Sample Code:**

```
GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory).setTransport(httpTransport).build().setAccessToken(accessToken);
AdWordsSession session = new AdWordsSession.Builder().withUserAgent(useragent).withOAuth2Credential(credentials).withDeveloperToken(DEVELOPER_TOKEN).build();
CustomerServiceInterface mcs = new AdWordsServices().get(session, CustomerServiceInterface.class);
Customer[] cs = mcs.getCustomers();
```

Is there any way to setting the timeout value for Adwords management apis?